# $X$ is exponentially distributed $\varepsilon(\theta)$. Using the Method of Maximum likelihood find the best (marking?)Question its centeredness

Tags: statistics, random-variables, sampling, maximum-likelihood

$X$ is exponentially distributed $\varepsilon(\theta)$. Using the Method of Maximum likelihood find the best (marking?)of sample $n$ for parameter $\theta$ .Question its centeredness and existence. Now I think I do not know the exact english translations of these notions so I will explain using the ones I do.

First of all I found out the the "marking" I am looking for is $$\overline{\theta_n}=\frac{1}{\overline{X_n}}$$ using miximum likihood method where $\overline{X_n}$ is the sample mean. Now by centeredness of the "marking" I mean that the expectation $E(\overline{\theta_n})=\overline{\theta}$ and existence meaning that $\overline{\theta_n}$ converges in probability to $\theta...$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand, you found the maximum-likelihood estimator of $\theta$, i.e.
$$
\hat\theta_n=\frac1{\overline X_n},
$$
and now you want to show that it is [unbiased](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bias_of_an_estimator) and [consistent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consistent_estimator).

We have that
$$
\operatorname E\hat\theta_n=\frac n{n-1}\theta
$$
(see [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/100636/bias-of-the-maximum-likelihood-estimator-of-an-exponential-distribution/100637#100637) for a complete explanation how to calculate this expected value). Hence, $\hat\theta_n$ is not an unbiased estimator.

By the weak law of large numbers,
$$
\overline X_n\to\frac1\theta
$$
in probability as $n\to\infty$. By the [continuous mapping theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_mapping_theorem),
$$
\hat\theta_n=\frac1{\overline X_n}\to\theta
$$
in probability as $n\to\infty$. Hence, $\hat\theta_n$ is a consistent estimator.